# How to deal with type in a Java parser?

Tags: java, parsing, antlr4

I'm learning antlr4 and trying to build a simple DSL(Domain Specific Language), as the backend of my appliction is developed in Java, the goal is to parse the DSL and run with the Java backend.  My DSL is a simplified version of Java and gose like this:

```
typeA a = expression;
```

The grammar and lexer is based on [this](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java8/pom.xml) .
It is like implementing Java with Java. Now the problem I got is in parsing statements like `typeA a = expression;` the type of variable `a` is only known at runtime and could be any type,  in th parse implementation I use classes to represent variables, expressions and variable values:

```
Variable{
  String identifier;
  int scopeId;
  //...
}
Value<T>{
  Exprssion<T> expression
  T get(){return expression.evaluate()}
  //...
}
Exprssion<T>{
  T evaluate(){return ...}
  //...
}
```

in the parser I need to have someting like this

```
new Expression<TypeA>(); 
new Value<TypeA>(); 
//to represent a assignment: 
Value<TypeA> va; ... va.set(vb.get());
```

These will not work as generics are a compile thing and TypeA can only be determined at runtime, even if I use Object as the generic type T I still need to cast the value to TypeA at some point, what is the right way to handle this in general?

Comment: People often try to do too much during parsing, and end up with a complicated solution that usually doesn't work.   Separate parsing from type analysis.  Decide what your grammar is, build a parser to process that and build an abstract syntax tree.   Then implement a pass over the tree to realize a symbol table, and do the type analysis during that pass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a non-trivial task if you want to allow arbitrary types. What you need is a [Type System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system), which is responsible to handle each possible type in your DSL. You cannot use generics for that (as you already found out) but have to provide classes in your type system that allow to use a certain type in expressions. They will check the validity of types (name, value domain) and execute possible operations, implicit/explicit conversions to other types etc.

Comment: A type System is indeed what I need and I've found a concrete implementation of the Java language in [BeanShell](https://github.com/beanshell/beanshell). For now I'll just restrict to a few types to make it easy to implement as my DSL is quite simple.